# Intellij, JaCoCo for Kotlin coverage

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, jacoco

I use IntelliJ with Kotlin and I use JaCoCo to compute tests coverage. In IntelliJ my code is covered, but I don't see the line covered percentage for my Kotlin classes. I can see it only for Java:

[image: coverage]

On the other hand my Kotlin classes are covered, my code is green or red. Also when I click on `Generate Coverage Report ...` in Coverage Window, it generates HTML pages and everything is very well covered.

Could you please tell me why I don't see line covered percentage in my Kotlin classes?

Comment: You can use IntelliJ's built-in coverage functionality which supports kotlin

Comment: How I can use  IntelliJ's built-in coverage functionality ?

Comment: Right click the test module in the file tree and click "run all tests with coverage"

Comment: No, still doesn't work for Kotlin classes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known problem in IDE. Please follow the related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10081